# Background image not showing up in IE7 only when served from Windows Server

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, windows-server

I have a background image on an h2 that is showing up in IE7 when served from my Linux server but not when served from my windows server:

```
#QandA .question h2, #QandA .question h3 {
        background:url(../images/nav_level2_closed.gif) no-repeat -20px -1px;
    padding-left : 25px;
}
```

I have tried using quotes on the url, using non-relative references, as well as made sure that the filename specified is exactly the same as the filename on the server (when viewing the file list through WS-FTP)

Any ideas would be mighty appreciated.

Comment: I should also mention that I can enter the url of the image directly into the browser and it shows up.

Comment: Do you have a `base href=` set in the header?

Comment: can you try with a different image? (just to test if the original has somekind of error, even if you can open it directly).

Comment: @jackjoe - yes I already did that, no difference

Comment: are these on public servers? It may be helpful if we could look at the page.

Comment: Unfortunately no... was hoping someone would just have an "aha" moment :) It's the strangest thing I've seen yet... works find on the linux server, just not on the windows server. and only in IE7. IE8, Firefox, etc. work fine on both servers.

Comment: I'm assuming you have IIS on the windows server, or is it apache? Are you trying the browsers on different machines or are you using IE7 mode in an IE8/9 browser to test this? IIS sometimes has weird caching issues with files.

Comment: @Vassi - I actually don't know much about the windows server, it's locked down and I only have ftp access. I'm using IE8 and testing it in all three modes (IE7, IE7 compatibility and IE8).